# Hive error after the command 'show databases;'

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, hive, metastore

Hi I am beginner to hadoop,
I just installed hive 2.3.7 and setup the metastore with mysql
according to this tutorial https://www.guru99.com/hive-metastore-configuration-mysql.html
and this one https://ravi-chamarthy.medium.com/apache-hive-configuration-with-mysql-metastore-3ecb9a0df3a1.
Here is my hdfs-site.xml file

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hiveuser</value>
    <description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description>
</property>
<property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>hivepassword</value>
    <description>password for connecting to mysql server</description>
</property>
```

When I executed **schematool -initSchema -dbType mysql**
everything is fine. It initialize the 2.3.0 schema of hive.
when I started hive and execute the command **show databases;** or any other,
I got this errors

```
hive> show databases;
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is
generally unnecessary.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.collect.Iterators.emptyIterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator; from class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.<init>(FetchOperator.java:108)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.initialize(FetchTask.java:87)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:541)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1317)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1457)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:318)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:232)
```

Note: I used mysql 8.0.22, mysql-connector-java.jar, mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar
ubuntu 18.04, hadoop 3.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Hadoop are you using? Might have to do with incompatible version of hadoop